# Filter Results with Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that totals dollar amounts for the current year [CY] and the previous year [PY] for my active companies. I need to add a parameter that will allow me to switch what is displayed based on the previous year amount sum.

Any companies that list 0 for PY sum would be a new company within the past year, and any that have a positive value in PY sum would be considered existing.

Is there a way to create the parameter so I can switch between them?  So far this is what I have

Query:

```
SELECT
  MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.cmp_code
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.cmp_name
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.Owner
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.[Year]
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.[CY Dollars]
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.[PY Dollars]
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.SalesPersonNumber
  ,MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.OwnerLastName
FROM
  MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY
WHERE
  MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.[Year] = @Year
  AND MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.Week <= @Week
  AND MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.SalesPersonNumber IN (@SalesPersonNumber)
  AND MW.MW_Submitted_Weeks_ROY.[Group] IS NOT NULL
```

The report is grouped on cmp_code. 
[image: report]

Edit:

I created a parameter called Store, and gave it values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter to your grouping clause based on a parameters that allows to filter on the conditions you described or show all. Something like

**Using a Group Filter Expression with Parameters**

Group1 Filter Expression

```
=(
  (Parameters!CompanyFilter.Value=2) 
  OR 
  (Parameters!CompanyFilter.Value=1 AND (IsNothing(SUM(PY_Dollars.Value)) OR SUM(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)=0) 
  OR
  (Parameters!Company.Value=0 AND SUM(Fields!CT_Dollars.Value)>0)
)
```

This would exclude any records that do not meet the criteria from being counted in the results.

Comment: I see the logic here but what do I put in for the operator and the value fields on the filter screen of group properties?

Comment: 1 = <expression> OR true=<expression>

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding out this is supposed to work. I still get an error when running the report. I'm not sure if maybe there is an issue with the expression you wrote with typos? Or if I'm just too dumb to get it.

Comment: Sorry, I may have omitted a closing paren. AND (IsNothing(SUM(PY_Dollars.Value)) OR SUM(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)=0)

Comment: It is basically returning a bool that you can filter in your condition =(True=FILTER)...pseudo code IF (PARAMETER=BOTH) RETURN(TRUE) ELSE IF (PARAMTER=NULL_OR_ZERO) RETURN (SUM=0) ELSE IF (PARAMETER=GREATER_THAN_ZERO) RETURN (SUM>0). This should return only records within the report parameter condition.

Comment: So my parameter values should be just integers correct? 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, or an optional 3 for both conditions, if you want to support an ALL options.

Comment: OK after adding that other ) i'm still getting the error where it's asking for another closing ). Also, in the expression you have values for the parameter as 0, 1, 2 listed. Here's what I have now in the expression field.

=(
  (Parameters!Store.Value=2) 
  OR 
  (Parameters!Store.Value=1 AND (IsNothing(SUM(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)) OR (SUM(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)=0)) 
  OR
  (Parameters!Store.Value=0 AND SUM(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)>0)
)

Comment: I think I figured it out. There also needs to be a parenthesis at teh end of (Parameters!Store.Value=0 AND SUM(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)>0)). 

How would i change this to do both?

Comment: I think that's correct there should be two conditions (Condition1)OR(Condition2)OR(OptionalAll) if you use OptionalAll then it would always return true because all means no filter. I hope this helps :) Fixed my typo in the answer above